# django rest model permissions

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 2.1 and djangorestframework 3.9.2.  I wish to be able to control access to REST operations on Django model objects via the Django admin interface, ideally using user permissions.  For example, only users who have read permissions on model object Foo should be able to see Foo in my REST API.

I read [the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/) and it seems maybe I could use [DjangoModelPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions) or [DjangoObjectPermissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangoobjectpermissions).

However, when I clear all user permissions in the DB, and set DEFAULT_PERMISSIONS_CLASS to either DjangoModelPermissions or DjangoObjectPermissions, I am still able to see things in the REST API.  That means lack of permissions is not preventing me from seeing objects as I hoped.

Example settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

An example object view:

```
from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets
from .models import Example

class ExampleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        fields = '__all__'

class ExampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Example.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ExampleSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'examples', ExampleViewSet)
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the view you are expecting to be affected by these permission settings as well? From the docs: "This permission must only be applied to views that have a .queryset property set." Could this be the cause?

Comment: Added, thanks. I just took a simple example from the docs, but I can't find the exact spot.

Comment: Another thing is, __DjangoModelPermissions__ only enforce permission rules for data modification (for __POST__ , __PUT__ , __PATCH__ and __DELETE__ requests), but does not enforce permission rules for data viewing. To restrict data viewing, you can add a custom view permisson, and subclass __DjangoModelPermissions__ to use that permission, as explained here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions

Comment: Oh thanks! If you submit that as an answer, i'll accept. Sadly, it says, "Refer to the source code for details" but now I know.

Comment: This seems like a bug, since there is a "view" Django permission. Should I submit it as an issue to the project?

Comment: As far as I can see, view permission is added to Django with version 2.1, so this is probably not a bug, but a feature not yet implemented. I think you should submit this as a feature request.

Comment: Ah, it's already submitted: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6324

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thank you. After a week I managed to find this answer. Appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

DjangoModelPermissions only enforce permission rules for data modification (for **POST** , **PUT** , **PATCH** and **DELETE** requests), but does not enforce permission rules for data viewing.

To restrict data viewing, you can add a custom view permisson, and subclass **DjangoModelPermissions** to use that permission, as explained in the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#djangomodelpermissions)

**EDIT:**

With Django 2.1, **view** model permission is added. So this will probably be supported by **DjangoModelPermissions** in the future releases, but until then, you can try subclassing DjangoModelPermissions like this to add check for view permissions:

```
class DjangoModelPermissionsWithRead(DjangoModelPermissions):
    perms_map = {
        'GET': ['%(app_label)s.view_%(model_name)s'],
        'OPTIONS': [],
        'HEAD': [],
        'POST': ['%(app_label)s.add_%(model_name)s'],
        'PUT': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'PATCH': ['%(app_label)s.change_%(model_name)s'],
        'DELETE': ['%(app_label)s.delete_%(model_name)s'],
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: There is [a feature request filed to support this](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/6324).