# Django Admin permissions applied on REST API views

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the django admin interface, it is possible to specify permissions on each individual Model. The permission options for an example model Customer are:

- Can add customer
- Can change customer
- Can delete customer
- Can view customer

However, these permissions do not seem to apply to REST Framework API Views (`rest_framework.viewsets.ModelViewSet`), implemented for `Customer` as follows:

```
class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer

class CustomerSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = '__all__'
```

I thought that by setting the DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES to DjangoModelPermissions these permissions would be reflected, but it does not:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissions',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),
}
```

Should the permissions defined in admin work in Views as well with these settings, should they not, and/or is there any way to make this happen? The benefit is that system administrators can easily define groups in the admin interface and tailor their permissions to their problem areas, so being able to define permissions in this way is very desireable. I have seen many other ways of implementing permissions, but they require from what I have seen a lot of customization on the View definitions in python.

Versions:

- Django 2.2.9
- djangorestframework 3.11.0
- djangorestframework-simplejwt 4.4.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For API views to check for groups and permissions, we can use DjangoModelPermission in our views.py as follows.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions

class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = (DjangoModelPermissions, )
```

It restricts POST, PUT and DELETE access but allows GET access. To restrict it also

```
from rest_framework.permissions import DjangoModelPermissions

class CustomDjangoModelPermissions(DjangoModelPermissions):
    def __init__(self):
        self.perms_map['GET'] = ['%(app_label)s.view_%       (model_name)s']


class CustomerViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Customer.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    permission_classes = (CustomDjangoModelPermissions, )
```

Comment: Great! I wasn't aware it allowed GET access, so that's why I was confused. With your exact code I got an error like ```return [perm % kwargs for perm in self.perms_map[method]]``` - ```not enough arguments to format string```, but was able to get it working with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55504648/django-rest-model-permissions/55505052#55505052